# Error when push Liberty for Java application in IBM Bluemix

Tags: java, cloud, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

when I run sample IBM Bluemix Liberty for Java application  https://github.com/ibmjstart/bluemix-java-postgresql-uploader.git following error:

```
-----> Downloaded app package (1.9M)
-----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (4.0K)
OK

/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:101:in build_pack': Unable to detect a supported application type (RuntimeError) from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:74:inblock in compile_with_timeout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in timeout' from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:73:incompile_with_timeout'
from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:54:in block in stage_application' from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:50:inchdir'
from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:50:in stage_application' from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/bin/run:10:in'

FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 170001, message: Staging error: cannot get instances since staging failed

TIP: use 'cf logs jpu-henryhan --recent' for more information
```

Answer (score 3):

The top error looks like you left off the `-p <path_to_war>` parameter when doing a push. If you just push a directory containing a WAR file, it will not be detected by the Java buildpack.

Answer (score 1):

The tip provided in the output of your cf push request is relevant.

```
 TIP: use 'cf logs jpu-henryhan --recent' for more information
```

Running that command will tail the log files produced during the staging process and let you see what error may have been raised. Often, it can be a missing dependency or a transient failure of some sort.

I just successfully deployed the sample using the "deploy to Bluemix" button and manually via the cf command line tool. Unless you changed the code, it is most likely that this error is a transient failure.

Answer (score 0):

Run following command:

```
$ cf push jpu- -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack --no-manifest --no-start -p PostgreSQLUpload.war
```

add the parameter to set the buildpack "-b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack"